# How to force phonegap ask for geolocation every time app starts?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova, geolocation

Im usiging phonegap to build an ios aplication and i use this code to get the current position of the user

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccsess, geolocationError);
```

but with this it ask's for permission just once when the app starts, i want to force it to ask every time its start's.

is there a way to do that?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it only asks once is that it only has to. The browser remembers it for some time, it will appear again only when necessary.